# Does the term "home" also mean "family"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice

> A young black American soldier leaves his home and family to cross
>   the ocean to put an end to the German nightmare.

I have just translated this sentence into English and I would like to know if in this context it is necessary to write the word "family" also, or if I can just write "the soldier leaves his home to cross etc." is understandable too, or even make a difference by writing "he leaves his house and family".

Comment: If your idea is to emphasize the departure, in my opinion, you can use both.

Comment: Home can include more than family, such as community etc

Comment: They are not the same.  Someone may have a home without having a family. just as there are families who don't have homes.  It's perfectly possible (though unlikely for a young soldier) for someone to leave home and take their family with them.  Using "home and family" here emphasizes how much he's leaving behind.

Comment: @jamesqf Young can be ambiguous enough that I think it's a stretch to say it's unlikely a young soldier will take his family with him. My younger sister was born in a foreign country when our family was deployed there, and my father was a young soldier at the time. I don't disagree with you that home and family is being used for emphasis though.

Comment: @ColleenV - _Family_ in this context could mean spouse and children, or it could mean parents, siblings, and other extended family. Soldiers like your father may be accompanied by their wife and children, yet still leave family behind.

Comment: @J.R I think though that if you go out of the way to say they left their family behind, you aren't talking about the situation where their spouse and children are deployed with them and the civilian members of their family remain at home. I may be nitpicking a bit,  because in this context it seems clear that the soldier was deployed without family members,  but that's not always the case.

Comment: @ColleenV - When a 19-year-old soldier leaves his family to be shipped overseas, he's leaving his parents and younger siblings. When a 29-year-old soldier leaves his family for the same reason, he's often leaving behind his wife and young children. (Those aren't absolutes, but those are pretty good general rules.) That's more what I was trying to say.

Comment: @J.R Exactly,  but young soldier is ambiguous,  because it could mean a twenty something to some people, while others might think of just 20 or under.   Maybe if the context mentioned rank, it would be more clear how young the soldier was. On the other hand,  what I picture when I read soldier might be a lot different from what folks with a different background might picture.

Comment: Could whoever is voting to close please give some helpful advice on this?  Please do note, it's a new user.

Comment: @ColleenV: In a peacetime deployment a soldier could perhaps take family with him - I don't know current policies, or whether it depends on rank or other facors.  But I infer from the "put an end to the German nightmare" that it's a combat deployment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> A young black American soldier leaves his home and family to cross the
> ocean to put an end to the German nightmare.

Using **home** and **family** in this sentence adds extra weight to the soldier's sacrifice/decision.  It is stating he is leaving both a place he is familiar with (his home) as well as the people he cares about/people who care about him (his family).  It highlights that he is uprooting himself both physically as well as socially.

In regards **home** vs **family**:

Home and family can have emotional connotations:

> **Home** = A place that you live / have lived (probably long-term) that you have an emotional connection to.
>
> **Family** = (Mostly) permanent group of people (usually blood-related or by marriage) with whom you have a emotional connection.

**Home** can mean simply the place that you live.  It can also mean a special place that you live/ have lived.  Many people feel at home, regardless of the actual location, when they are with their family.  Thus, they may consider, their 'true' home, their family.

For example, a person who moves to a different city for a new job would live permanently in that new city.  The house in that city that they live in would be their new 'home'.  However, if that person felt a strong tie to their parent's house, for example, they may still consider their parent's house their 'home' despite no longer actually living there.

Less emotionally-charged phrasing for 'home' could be: 'his residence/house/apartment' and as an alternative for family: 'his relatives'.